# Trying to understand a probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand a probability question regarding a biased coin, not quite sure how to factor in the biased probability in the question, and also I wanted to make sure the answer is correct, as I think the lecturer might have made a mistake in one of them, which could possibly throw off everything else, and I don't know if it's just me being stupid.

Here is the question:

---

1.) A biased coin is flipped 4 times. The probability of the coin showing 'heads' is p = 3/4. Answer the following questions.

a) What is the probability that exactly 3 flips show 'heads'? Answer: $\frac{27}{60}$

b) What is the probability that at least three flips show heads? Answer: $\frac{189}{256}$

c) Given that three flips show 'heads' what is the probability that the last flip was a 'head'? Answer:  $\frac{3}{4}$

---

The only one I understand is the last one, unless a) presents an incorrect answer, then I understand that, because the answer I get is  $\frac{27}{64}$

So in short, I'd like to know how to do these types of questions, where it factors bias elements.

Comment: It is $\frac{27}{64}$. At least 3 flips can be interpreted as either 3 or 4 flips.

Comment: Can nobody help me out with 1b)? That's the only one I have no clue about :/

Comment: If you got the answer to "exactly 3 flips", I have a hard time believing that you can't also get the answer to "exactly 4 flips". Add them together. Although, the answer to that one also looks like a typo.

Comment: It doesn't say exactly 4 flips though, says, at least 3 flips :S

Comment: If you are flipping it 4 times, what does at least 3 flips mean? What are all the possible numbers of flips that can land heads?

Comment: That's what I don't know, it's just in the question, this is a sample exam paper.

Comment: Ok you seem alright at math but you might need to practice your English. The number of possible times a coin can land heads, after being flipped 4 times, is 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. You should work out the probabilities of each of these, separately. If you worked out part (a) then you should have no trouble with this. They should sum to 1, for 100%. For part (b) you should add the probabilities for 3 heads and 4 heads.

Comment: I don't know if you're referring to the wording of the questions, if so I did not write them, I was simply trying to interpret them, but couldn't, but if you are talking about how I explained what I was trying to accomplish, then fair enough. Rather insulting, but I'll let it slide since you gave me the correct answer, thank you so much, I did not think it would be that simple :)

Comment: I just meant interpreting what "at least three flips" means. And I didn't mean it as insulting, I just meant that half of doing math problems like this is first of all understanding what they are asking for. It is a skill that needs to be practiced just like arithmetic, and it looks like it's your bottleneck. It's amazing how many times I've seen somebody do a whole bunch of correct calculation and then write down the wrong number because they didn't read the problem closely enough.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the binomial distribution for this one.

Hints:

The coin flips can be treated as independent.

The heads and tails can be in any order, so you have to count how many ways they can be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Binomial distribution.

1 a) your answer is correct, likely a typo in the solution cited.

Comment: I done 1b through binomial distribution, but I just got $\frac{27}{64}$ again, so I seem to be missing something, or I'm going wrong somewhere.